# MySql error e.entity_id not found

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, database, mysql

Following is code to get entity_ids but MySql throw error `e.enitity_id` not found

```
$this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
->from(array('main_table' => 'catalog_product_entity'), array('entity_id'))
->join(
    array('w' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_website')),
    'main_table.entity_id=w.product_id',
    array()
)
->where('w.website_id=?', $store->getWebsiteId());
$this->_addFilter($storeId, 'visibility', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds(), 'in');
$this->_addFilter($storeId, 'status', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getVisibleStatusIds(), 'in');
```

What exactly wrong with above code?

Comment: try replacing `main_table` with `e`.

Comment: @Marius Then it will work but How to do it with `main_table`?

Comment: I think it won't work with `main_table`. It depends on how `_addFilter` looks like. I think that method uses `e` as a table alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get this "working" as Marius has pointed out you can simply replace the use of `main_table` with `e`.

```
$this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
->from(array('e' => 'catalog_product_entity'), array('entity_id'))
->join(
    array('w' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_website')),
    'e.entity_id=w.product_id',
    array()
)
->where('w.website_id=?', $store->getWebsiteId());
$this->_addFilter($storeId, 'visibility', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds(), 'in');
$this->_addFilter($storeId, 'status', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getVisibleStatusIds(), 'in');
```

The reasoning behind this is because the function `_addFilter` has the use of `e` hardcoded so you cannot specify your own alias for tables :(